# Can't add vertex with python in neptune workbench

Tags: amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I'm trying to put together a demo of Neptune using Neptune workbench, but something's not working right.  I've got this block set up:

```py
from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

graph = Graph()

cluster_url = #my cluster

remoteConn = DriverRemoteConnection( f'wss://{cluster_url}:8182/gremlin','g')

g = graph.traversal().withRemote(remoteConn)


import uuid

tmp = uuid.uuid4()
tmp_id=str(id)

def get_id(name):
    uid = uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, f"{name}.licensing.company.com")
    return str(uid)


def add_sku(name):
    tmp_id = get_id(name)
    g.addV('SKU').property('id', tmp_id, 'name', name)
    return name

def get_values():
    return g.V().properties().toList()
```

The problem is that calling `add_sku` doesn't result in a vertex being added to the graph.  Doing the same operation in a cell with gremlin magic works, and I can retrieve values through python, but I can't add vertices.  Does anyone see what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python code is not working because it is missing a [terminal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps) step (next() or iterate()) on the end of it which forces it to evaluate.  If you add the terminal step it should work:

```
g.addV('SKU').property('id', tmp_id, 'name', name).next()
```

Comment: for people landing on this, I used `.iterate()` instead of `.next()`